# how to break text-wrap in aspose.word for C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, line-breaks, aspose, aspose.words

I want to insert a break like MS-Word *text-wrap break*, but it is not exist in `BreakType` members:

```
 builder.InsertBreak(BreakType.????);
```

Comment: I guess this is just an intellisense failure. Does any of [those](https://apireference.aspose.com/net/words/aspose.words/breaktype) work ?

Answer (score 1):

Please check following code snippet. Hope this helps you.

```
Document doc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

builder.Writeln("Text wrapping breaks");
builder.InsertBreak(BreakType.LineBreak);
builder.Writeln("Page break");
builder.InsertBreak(BreakType.PageBreak);
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Could you please share some more detail of your issue? Please share expected output document. I will then share the code example. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Aspose.Words does not support the insertion of text-wrap break into document. We have logged this feature request as WORDSNET-11027 in our issue tracking system.

Comment: Hey Tahir I am trying to replace a text but it is shifting the rest of the text out of row .

Comment: Please share your input, output and expected output documents for investigation.